# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{'

Tags: php, phpunit, php-7

I'm try playing with php7. I have installed https://github.com/rlerdorf/php7dev and connected through phpstorm. 
I'm trying use new feature like this:

```
<?php
namespace Kata;

class StringCalculator
{
    public function add(string $parameters): int {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

then I try to test it like this:

```
<?php
namespace Kata;

class StringCalculatorTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testAddEmptyString()
    {
        $calc = new StringCalculator();
        $this->assertSame(0, $calc->add(''));
    }
}
```

and I launch with phpunit, unfortunately I have

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{'

Probably I haven't installed php7 properly but it seems to be ok when I php -v

> PHP 7.0.0-dev (cli) (built: May 25 2015 16:34:33) (DEBUG) Copyright
>   (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.0.0-dev, Copyright (c)
>   1998-2015 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies

UPDATE

Problem is not in installation/configuration php7 (I think), because when I run it from cli like this:

```
<?php
    $calc = new Kata\StringCalculator();
    var_dump($calc->add(''));
```

outputs `int(0)` and no error.

So maybe the problem is in phpunit?

Comment: PHP can be installed in different versions on a system. Also the CLI version can certainly be a different one than the one loaded as a module into an http server. Such things are easiest resolved using your systems software management system. You search for php and then simply compare the versions installed. Probably you have a mix installed. Or you can call the old and famous script `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to see what is loaded.

Comment: In which file and on which line do you get this error?

Comment: @Rizier123 obviously the function definition. That is how a function definition may look like in php7 if a return type is specified.

Comment: For me its look like function declaration in `class stringcalculator {} ` is the culprit. Have you checked the syntax?

Comment: @Rizier123 why is that odd? It is a syntax error. The method does not have to get called for that error to be raised. Loading the class definition is enough. That is exactly what the test does when trying to instantiate the object.

Comment: @Exception Yes, obviously that is the issue. And yes, the syntax is correct. _That_ is the issue.

Comment: @arkascha,  what exactly you mean by that syntax is correct and that is the issue?. Do you want to say that php is not recognizing this syntax?

Comment: @Exception Yes, sure. That is what the error says: "Syntax error". You may want to read the question again...

Comment: @arkascha, that doesn't sound like php is not installed properly or something is missing ..

Comment: @Exception The OP tries to use PHP7, but obviously the interpreter is an older version which is why it does not recognize that syntax.

Comment: @user3381230, in which platform you are installing php7, linux OR windows?

Comment: Syntax for php7 seems to be ok: https://3v4l.org/RV4QP.

Comment: @arkascha - phpinfo looks like this:  http://i.imgur.com/V9KGUSG.jpg

Comment: @Exception - I have installed for linux ( Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u1 x86_64 )

Comment: @user3381230 then you can look into my answer given below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error it is clear that there's a problem executing your code.

`PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{'`

The problem in your case is most likely coming from PHPUnit since you have a correct php 7 setup. If PHPUnit fails to understand your code it's gonna fail in the first bit of PHP 7 code which in your case using a [return type declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration)
in this line

```
public function add(string $parameters): int {
```

and it's gonna be triggered in your phpunit test when you try to assert. If you comment your assersion the error should disappear.

I suggest verifiying the version of PHPUnit you are using, you should use version 5 or higher. (preferably 6 for php 7.0)
For more details about PHPunit versions, checkout [this link](https://phpunit.de/).

Answer (score 0):

this is due to the fact that composer version is in misalignment with php version.
"laravel/framework": "^9.11" goes fine with php 8.1. After upgrading to php 8.1, no errors were shown