# Getting `PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{'`

Tags: parsing, url, syntax

How can I fix this error?

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /home/domainname/public_html/..../src/Parse/HttpClients/ParseCurlHttpClient.php on line 154

PHP sürümü: 7.3.6

Code where error occurs:

```
public function getResponseContentType()
{
    return $this->responseContentType;
}

/**
 * Sets up our cURL request in advance
 */
public function setup() : void     **//154 line**
{
    // init parse curl
    $this->parseCurl->init();

    $this->parseCurl->setOptionsArray(array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
        CURLOPT_HEADER          => 1,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 2,
    ));
}
```

Code repo: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-php-sdk/blob/master/src/Parse/HttpClients/ParseCurlHttpClient.php

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914266/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-expecting-or

Comment: I assume this comes from you trying to run a library on an old version of PHP. What version of PHP are you using? May we see a few lines of the code on line 154?

Comment: Code adress :https://github.com/parse-community/parse-php-sdk/blob/master/src/Parse/HttpClients/ParseCurlHttpClient.php  154 line

Comment: This library [seems to need PHP 7.1](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-php-sdk/blob/master/composer.json) or above. My guess is that it is being run on PHP 5.x, and your assessment that you're running on 7.3 is mistaken.

Comment: -Web sunucusu
cpsrvd 11.92.0.6
Veritabanı istemcisi sürümü: libmysql - 5.6.43
PHP uzantısı: mysqliBelgeler curlBelgeler mbstringBelgeler
PHP sürümü: 7.3.6   
-phpMyAdmin
Sürüm bilgisi: 4.9.5

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in Docker or similar? This library has 800 stars on GitHub, so it is highly likely you are doing something wrong. However your readers cannot tell what the issue is given the brief information provided.